# Are there poskim who sanction using nedarim today

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, modern-times

Are there major contemporary poskim (halachic authorities) who advocate making nedarim (vows) for certain circumstance (besides donations)?

for example, someone who has a bad habit, to use a nedar (vow) to break the bad habit.

Comment: AFAIK, today, vows are discouraged. Actually, so many religious people I speak to use the term *Bli neder* to avoid making a vow. (Perhaps, occasionally, the term is overused by some, as it becomes a habitual expression that they use even when no vow could possibly occur, as in "Bli Neder, I can't cook on Shabbat." Doesn't make sense!)

Comment: For instance: "My house should be forbidden like a Korban to all Meshullachim."

Answer (score 2):

Vows have always been discouraged. In fact, the *gemara* in *Masechet Nedarim* specifically mentions certain *halachot* of *nedarim* exist to discourage the light usage of *nedarim*.

Nonetheless, your example of using *nedarim* to break (at least certain) bad habits is indeed something that at least some major contemporary poskim support. [GuardYourEyes.org](http://www.guardyoureyes.org) is a resource for people who have addictions related to *shmiras ha-eynaim* on the internet. They openly advocate *nedarim* to break pornography addictions as one of the intermediate steps in their program. They have [haskamot](https://guardyoureyes.com/haskamos) from many well-known and respected contemporary poskim including Rav Aharon Feldman, Rabbi Dr. Avraham Twersky, and others.

The formulas that the website mentions might not technically be considered *nedarim* under the most literal definition of the term; however, they are commonly referred to as *nedarim*, and could potentially be formulated in a way that is a technical *neder*.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16808/759

Comment: Rabbi Hershel Schachter tells of one rosh yeshiva who passed away about ten years ago would continuously make a neder to quit his smoking addiction, find it impossible to keep, and have it annulled. This process repeated far too many times. Rabbi Schachter commented that he should not be using a neder in this circumstance.

Comment: @Shalom the _nedarim_ advocated by GYE have a time limit. Once one is finding it easier, he increases the time limit

Comment: @Shalom does that mean that if it worked R.Schachter would say it is good what he did?

Comment: @Daniel those haskomos are not specifically on the nedarim. more like generally on what they are doing. also here are their 12 steps https://guardyoureyes.com/the-12-steps dont see nedarim openly. its an obscure part of their site

Comment: @ray The 12-step program isn't something that GYE invented. That's the same program used by Alcoholics Anonymous and other related support groups. It's tool #15 in their ["20 Progressive Tools"](https://guardyoureyes.com/the-gye-program/20-tools). Using _nedarim_ is part of the [Tool 10: Extra Strong Fences - TaPhSiC Method](https://guardyoureyes.com/the-gye-program/20-tools/item/tool-10?category_id=278). I assume that the rabanim who gave their haskamos at least read through the 20 progressive tools. Otherwise, how could they give their haskamah?

Comment: because people addicted to pornography are in a kind of spiritual pikuach nefesh. i'm looking for less extreme cases.

Comment: @ray You didn't mention that in the question. How extreme is too extreme?

Comment: like i said addiction to pornography is so bad for one religiously that i suspect they would be highly lenient. cant really learn from there to other places like quitting smoking for example

Comment: @ray I didn't say you could... You asked if there are poskim who advocate using nedarim in certain circumstances. I gave an example of poskim advocating using nedarim in certain circumstances.

Comment: ah sorry for not being clear enough. thanks for your answer